# How to unlink a DevOps repo in Databricks Repos?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-databricks, azure-repos

I linked this DevOps repo inside my Databricks workspace Repos, but now I want to get rid of it.

And no matter how much I've searched, I can't find a way to do something that looks this simple.

I would have expected a button or an option like "Remove Repo", but that doesn't exist.

[This is what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZXvN.png)

Thank you.